# Running a custom hook after fixing a function

Tags: callback, ide, editor, hook, dyalog

Using Dyalog APL 16, is it possible to define a function which is called directly after a function is fixed (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `AfterFix` event existed already in 16.0, even though it was undocumented. However, it is identical to the event as it exists in later versions, so **see [the documentation](https://help.dyalog.com/latest/#GUI/MethodOrEvents/AfterFix.htm)** but note that the callback for this event is used by SALT (and Link), so you'll lose that functionality unless you modify `⎕SE.SALTUtils.EditorFix` to call your function in addition to taking its own actions. The source file for this function can be queried with `⎕SE.SALTUtils.SALT_Data.SourceFile`.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! `(⎕SE.⎕WG'Editor')⎕WS 'Event' 'AfterFix' 'MyFunction'